# How to split a string by one or many occurrences of a single character

Tags: c#

I have a string such as the following:

```
string a = "foo,,,,,,,bar, baz, qux";
```

Usually `a.Split(",")` would be okay to split a string by the comma, but with the above situation it would result in many empty strings due to the commas.

Is there a simple way to split a string by one or many occurrences of the separator, so that the result would be something like `["foo","bar","baz","qux"]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `StringSplitOptions` to remove the empty results.

In **.NET Core**, you can pass a single character to `string.Split` and use `StringSplitOptions`

```
var output = a.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

In **.NET Framework**, you have to pass the single char in a char array (`char[]`) like so:

```
var output = a.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Innat3 and @Fildor for pointing out differences in Core and Framework.

Comment: you need to pass a character array, otherwise it won't compile

Comment: hmm you must be compiling with .Net Core or Mono, you can see for yourself [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zJzLWC)

Comment: @Inat3 is correct: in .Net Core 3 this is valid: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oZLfuX, in framework, it's not. I'd suggest to just add the other version to the answer and pointing out the platform differences.

Comment: For reference: [Framework 4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8), [.NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: Updated with both versions. Thanks both of you. Didn't realize there was a difference when it came to `Split`. I was using .NET Core

Comment: Wasn't aware neither just until 11 minutes ago, tbh :)

Comment: Thank you guys, this has solved the issue! Yes,  we've all learnt something new!

Answer (score 3):

use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var parts = a.Split(new [] {',',' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

The unfortunate part in some versions of .NET is that you *have* to pass an array of delimiters with this method rather than a single delimiter, but the output is what you want.

Comment: _"you have to pass an array of delimiters"_ not in .Net Core 3.0 : [Split(Char, StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.0#System_String_Split_System_Char_System_StringSplitOptions_)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `LINQ`

```
var x = a.Split(",").Select(s=>s.Trim()).Where(x => x.Length > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The a.Split(",") method has an overload that lets you exclude empty elements

```
a.Split(",", System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: If your delimiter is a string as in your example the overload as shown works, if your delimiter is a Char you will need to pass it as a single element array

Comment: There seems to be a difference, depending on the platform (Framework / Mono / Core) what overloads are available.

Comment: @Fidor, Yes you're right Core has the string overload, Framework hasn't, Don't know about Mono

Answer (score -1):

You can use linq:

```
string a = "foo,,,,,,,bar, baz, qux";

var result = a.Split(',').Where(s => s.Length > 0)
var trimmedResult = result.Select(s => s.Trim())

foreach (var s in result) Console.WriteLine(s);  // "foo,bar, baz, qux"
foreach (var s in trimmedResult) Console.WriteLine(s);   // "foo,bar,baz,qux"
```